# Incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin

After updating to intellij 2023.3 my plugin is incompatible and does not build anymore

**Build error**

> .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/2023.3/6105b81c6142f62379ad6c5afb542c77350a71eb/ideaIC-2023.3/lib/app-client.jar!/META-INF/intellij.platform.analysis.impl.kotlin_module:
> Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary
> version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
  id("java")
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.7.22"
  id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.16.1"
}

group = “mygroup”
version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

intellij {
    version.set("2023.3") // updated from 2023.2.2
    type.set("IC")

    plugins.set(listOf("Git4Idea"))
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0")
}

tasks {
    withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = "17"
        targetCompatibility = "17"
    }
    withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
    }

    patchPluginXml {
        sinceBuild.set("231.9392.1")
    }

    signPlugin {
        certificateChain.set(System.getenv("CERTIFICATE_CHAIN"))
        privateKey.set(System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY"))
        password.set(System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD"))
    }

    publishPlugin {
        token.set(System.getenv("PUBLISH_TOKEN"))
    }
}
```